# Footage settings in Masking workspace seem stuck on 1920x1080, need 3840x1080, how to change?

Tags: video, masking, dimensions

Is it even possible to change the Footage Settings in the Masking Workspace? I hit "N" to bring up the tab, and in Footage Settings there seems no way to change them from 1920x1080, even going to other workspaces... my footage is 3840x1080, anamorphic, and I used a scaling modifier in nodes to correct it, but the edges are cut every time I export.[image]

Comment: Intention is stated in the subject; please see image for details

Comment: Apparently the expertise here is quite limited.